# SVG / CSS Text Centering on Viewport Change

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to position a text element in an SVG block, so that when the div its in changes width, that the text itself centers within the div. It starts as left aligned (so no x is defined) in a div that is 75% at full screen, but when it hits 768 viewport (media query), the div goes to 100% width, and the SVG needs to be centered within it.

My code at desktop and with media query:

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.left img {
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  float: left;
}

svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.serif {
  font-family: 'Times';
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 50px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px;
) {
  .left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="left"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/237x88/000/fff.png"></div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <svg viewBox='0 0 500 100'>
      <text class='serif' y='43%'>Header</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I can't test the media query here.

So essentially, how can I senter the SVG text when the `.wrapper` goes to 100%

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-anchor:middle;` and move the text to the middle of the viewBox with a CSS `transform`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px;
) {
  .left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .serif {
    text-anchor: middle;
    transform: translateX(250px);
}
```